# Ember JS 1.8.1 + Chrome - Additional whitespaces

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, grunt-ember-templates

I have a problem in the app that I'm working on, **since I upgraded EmberJS from 1.6.1 to 1.8.1**. It happens **only under Chrome**. The issue is that somehow my templates are being rendered with lots of additional spaces surrounding each html node. So to say... instead of:

```
<div>
[tab]<span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

I get something like this rendered:

```
<div>[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ]<span>Hello</span>[ ][ ][ ][ ]
</div>[ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Or maybe you'll see it here:
[image: An example]

That obviously breaks styling a lot. The funny thing is that when I remove at least one space from such strange construct, then magically the styling for given section is back (even though other spaces are still there).

Just to mention. **I'm using ember-grunt-templates 0.4.21 to compile**. I know that there are new versions of it (0.4.23 I think...) and I tried to update it as well, but it doesn't help.

I know that there was a mention here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/11/04/ember-1-8-1-released.html about whitespace issue in Chrome, but it says that people get the opposite effect of missing spaces due to some bug in Chrome. ;> Is my Chrome instance consuming and gathering all other people whitespaces or what? :-)

Anyone encountered similar issue (like mine, not like the one mentioned in Ember release notes)? Anyone knows how to get rid of this?

**Update 1:**

I tried to update to:

- Ember 1.9
- Handlebars 2.0
- Grunt-Ember-Templates 0.5 alpha

That fixes few occurrences of whitespace issue, but some are still present. I.e. that results in a space in front of rendered text:

```
<span class="someClass">
    {{#if condition}}{{someProperty}}{{else}}{{t 'translationKey'}}{{/if}}
</span>
```

And that doesn't:

```
<span class="someClass">{{#if condition}}{{someProperty}}{{else}}{{t 'translationKey'}}{{/if}}</span>
```

:-|

Comment: Is your editor converting tabs to 4 spaces?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a line ending encoding related bug. I reported that issue here:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9945

Solution is to make sure that line ending encoding has to be Unix-like.